# How to change characters in a text file using C's mmap()?

Tags: c

Let's say I have the standard "Hello, World! \n" saved to a text file called hello.txt. If I want to change the 'H' to a 'R' or something, can I achieve this with mmap()?

Comment: Yes you can. Once you `mmap` the file you can read and write to it like a regular memory buffer.

Comment: Check the man page for mmap and the example given in the man page. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html  You can modify the contents of the file by accessing and writing at the addr in the example given.

Answer (score 5):

`mmap` does not exist in the standard C99 (or C11) specification. It is defined in POSIX.

So assuming you have a POSIX system (e.g. Linux), you could first [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) the file for read & write:

```
int myfd = open("hello.txt", O_RDWR);
if (myfd<0) { perror("hello.txt open"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Then you get the size (and other meta-data) of the file with [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html):

```
struct stat mystat = {};
if (fstat(myfd,&mystat)) { perror("fstat"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Now the size of the file is in `mystat.st_size`.

```
off_t myfsz = mystat.st_size;
```

Now we can call  [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and we need to *share* the [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) (to be able to write inside the file thru the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space))

```
void*ad = mmap(NULL, myfsz, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 
               myfd, 0);
if (ad == MMAP_FAILED) { perror("mmap"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Then we can overwrite the first byte (and we check that indeed the first byte in that file is `H`  since you promised so):

```
assert (*(char*ad) == 'H');
((char*)ad) = 'R';
```

We might call [msync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html) to ensure the file is updated right now on the disk. If we don't, it could be updated later.

Notably for very large mappings (notably those much larger than available RAM), we can assist the kernel (and its [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)) with hints given thru [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) or [posix_madvise(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_madvise.3.html)...

Notice that a mapping remains in effect even after a [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html). Use `munmap` & `mprotect` or `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` on the same address range  to change them.

On Linux, you could use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to query the address space. So your program could read (e.g. after `fopen`, using `fgets` in a loop) the pseudo `/proc/self/maps` file (or `/proc/1234/maps` for process of pid 1234).

BTW, `mmap` is used by [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html); it can be called a lot of times, my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) program demonstrates that on Linux you could have many hundreds of thousands of `dlopen`-ed shared files (so many hundreds of thousands of memory mappings).

Comment: You don't actually need to round up the length to the page size. In fact, unless you want to extend the file in question, you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <sys/mman.h>

    int main(){
       int myFile = open("hello.txt", O_RDWR);
       if(myFile < 0){
           printf("open error\n");
       }
       struct stat myStat = {};
       if (fstat(myFile, &myStat)){
           printf("fstat error\n");
       }

       off_t size = myStat.st_size;
       char *addr;
       addr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, myFile, 0);
       if (addr == MAP_FAILED){
           printf("mmap error\n");
       }
       if (addr[0] != 'H'){
           printf("Error: first char in file not H");
       }
       addr[0] = 'J';
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: also, if "#include <fcnt1.h>" is giving you problems, replace the "1" with a lower case "l" as in lion so it's "#include <fcntl.h>"